# Can a simple boolean value be used as lock for async code?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo, middleware

When we get an accessToken expired back from our API we will try to refresh the accessToken using a refresh token. We can have a scenario where we send 5-10 requests in parallel ( or as parallel as one can do in JS), and all those 5-10 requests will trigger our refresh token handler function.

We only want one instance of the refresh handler function to be invoked.

In production it looks like `await refresh();` gets called multiple time in a row. But when i test locally and in unit tests, `await refresh();` gets called 1 time and the rest of the calls get postponed.

Is there something wrong with the `let notLocked= true;` approach?

```js
let refreshToken = 0 // just use a number here to represent a token
const refresh = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Fake a call that takes some time and increment the refresh token, 
    // so we can see that it has been changed
    refreshToken++;
    resolve();
  }, 1000)
})

let notLocked = true;
// in our case this could be a reference to a fetch request. e.g a http get method to ...api/tasks
const originalRequest = (msg) => console.log(msg)

const asyncWrapper = async() => {
  if (notLocked) {
    try {
      notLocked = false;
      await refresh();
      originalRequest('refreshed: ' + refreshToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Could not handle refresh token flow', error);
    } finally {
      notLocked = true;
    }
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      originalRequest('postponed');
    }, 2500)

  }
};

asyncWrapper();
asyncWrapper();
asyncWrapper();

/*

Output (OK, but the result is different in production):

postponed ​​​​​

postponed ​​​​​

refreshed: 1 ​​​​​

*/
```

The code lives in a redux middleware function

Would it be better to put the setting the lock, outside the async code? E.g:

```js
 let refreshToken = 0 // just use a number here to represent a token
    const refresh = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Fake a call that takes some time and increment the refresh token, 
    // so we can see that it has been changed
    refreshToken++;
    resolve();
  }, 1000)
})

let notLocked = true;
// in our case this could be a reference to a fetch request. e.g a http get method to ...api/tasks
const originalRequest = (msg) => console.log(msg)

const action = () => {
    if(notLocked){
        notLocked = false;
        const asyncWrapper = async () => {
                try {
                    await refresh();
                    originalRequest('refreshed: ' + refreshToken);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('Could not handle refresh token flow', error);
                } finally {
                    notLocked = true;
                }
        };
       asyncWrapper();
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
            originalRequest('postponed');
        },2500)
    }
}

action();
action();
action();
```

Comment: You can't guarantee the order. So I don't think you can do this.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Doesn't that mean that execution may be transferred between the evaluation of the `if` statement and the temporary locking through `notLocked` ? Is JS asynchronicity that fine-grained ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe I'm not knowledgeable enough to answer.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for your comments! I don't care about the order just that one refresh and the rest get post poned. Is that what you meant? Could it be that all the requests just races past `if (notLocked)` and all has an old/initial value of notLocked? Or is that the same as what you said @collapsar? :)

Comment: In your actual production code is `originalRequest` performing an async request? if so you probably should await it. In this code if that function is doing something async you will unlock before it finishes.

Comment: Oh also, is there logic to actually postpone the requests when they encounter the locked section? In this code you haven't shown how that logic would work.

Comment: @ChrisRollins Yes! good point. In the production code the timeout for the orignalRequest is 2500 and not 100. I updated the examples to reflect this. Regarding your second question. I think the samples will become a bit too complex if i include it. In our acutal code, the originalRequest will be dispatched through a middleware pipeline and send again. If it fails. it will be catched in our httpMiddlware again.

Comment: Is it possible that the scoping is different in production causing each call to this function to have a different copy of the notLocked variable?

Comment: @ChrisRollins that could be. Our code is written in TypeScript and is run on a mobile browser javascript engine on android (react native)

Comment: Thought of another possibility. Does the real version of the `refresh` function await everything it does so that when you await it, the token will be refreshed before you proceed to call originalRequest?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure @ChrisRollins. The refresh will await a response from a fetch request. After that it will dispatch a redux action with a new set of tokens. From my experience the tokens will be set before originalRequest gets called, because the tokens action will be queued before the originalRequest will get queued again. But suppose the orginalAction gets called before the tokens are set what would the consequences be? My assumption is that it just fails the api call again, and try to refresh, but will be postponed, because the lock is still active

Comment: In this code the lock will be released before the response from originalRequest comes back because you are not awaiting originalRequest. So if the token is not actually available before you call originalRequest it could explain the issue.